# How do I set the background img over the footer

Tags: html, css, background-image

I want the picture to cover everything on the page but the `<header>` however, there is always a white strip of space on the bottom.
I used `margin-right` and `margin-left` to cover the sides, but `margin-bottom` does not fill in the white space on the bottom.

```css
header {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
nav {
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#wrapper {
  background-image: url(rome.jpg);
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 600px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 600px;
  margin-right: -8px;
  margin-left: -8px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Colin Bruin</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="home.html">Home</a>
      </li>|
      <li><a href="code.html">Code</a>
      </li>|
      <li><a href="webpages.html">Webpages</a>
      </li>|
      <li><a href="articles.html">Articles</a>
      </li>|
      <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div id="wrapper">

  <main>

  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: your code doesnt have a `footer` element (or a `#footer` element)..

Comment: @haxxxton, I can not see how this is related to user's question at all.

Comment: Use CSS3 `background-size: contain;` or `background-size: cover;` for your `#wrapper` element.

Comment: @RuslanAbuzant, but the question is about "How do I set the background img over the footer".. dont we need one in order to be setting a background image over it?

Answer (score 2):

`body` has by default some `margin` that's why you are seeing that bottom space so as the left/right space too (which you used negative margin to *hack fix* it).

To solve this set `margin:0` in `body`, and you won't need the negative `margin`s for left/right

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
header {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
nav {
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#wrapper {
  background-image: url(//lorempixel.com/1000/1000);
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 600px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Colin Bruin</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="home.html">Home</a>
      </li>|
      <li><a href="code.html">Code</a>
      </li>|
      <li><a href="webpages.html">Webpages</a>
      </li>|
      <li><a href="articles.html">Articles</a>
      </li>|
      <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div id="wrapper">
 <main>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: You answered first, but my answer has a kitten!! :P

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```css
height:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;

}
header {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
nav {
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#wrapper {
  background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/g/1000/1000);
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 600px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 600px;
}
</style> </head>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Colin's Page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Colin Bruin</h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="home.html">Home</a>
          </li>|
          <li><a href="code.html">Code</a>
          </li>|
          <li><a href="webpages.html">Webpages</a>
          </li>|
          <li><a href="articles.html">Articles</a>
          </li>|
          <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="wrapper">

      <main>

      </main>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```